# aspnet_compiler platform:x86

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a c# web site (not a web application project) in a .net solution which is using a third party component.
The third party component requires the client to compile code in x86 platform.

I can specify the platform in csc.exe but could not find a way to specify for aspnet_compiler.exe

Now when I build the solution it fails and complains that can not validate web site and can not load the component.

wondering if is there any way to specify platform or any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set custom compiler option on web.config on the `<compilers>`

```
compilerOptions="/platform:string"
```

where string can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4(VS.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9x69bzw.aspx

Also, on iis7, on the advanced settings of the pool, there is the "Enable 32-Bit applications" that Is the one that make you app compile and run on 32 bit or on 64 bit.